# How to classify extracted relations (NLP)?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, classification, stanford-nlp, text-mining

There are some not labeled corpus. I extracted from it triples (OBJECT, RELATION, OBJECT). For relation extraction I use Stanford OpenIE. But I need only some of this triples. For example, I need relation "***funded***".

***Text***:
`Every startup needs a steady diet of funding to keep it strong and growing. Datadog, a monitoring service that helps customers bring together data from across a variety of infrastructure and software is no exception. Today it announced a massive $94.5 million Series D Round. The company would not discuss valuation.`

From this text i want to extract relation `(Datadog, announced, $94.5 million Round)`

I have only one idea:

1. Use StanfordCoreference to detect that 'Datadog' in the first sentence and 'it' in second sentence are the same entity
2. Try to cluster relations, but i think it's won't work well

May be there are better approach? May be I need labeled corpus(i haven't it)?

Comment: You might get more/better feedback if you clarified your question. Specifically, relation `funded` vs relation `announced` and `one idea` vs two items in the list below. The common term for "not labelled" is "unsupervised." Also, clustering relations isn't going to help, because "announced" isn't related to "funding", but they announced a "funded" event ie it's the object, not the predicate that you're interested in here. Co-reference resolution is going to be required to make any progress here, regardless of the approach you take.